# Obtaining low weight stabilizer generators

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

Suppose I know a set of stabilizer generators of a qubit quantum code. Is there a systematic (and possibly efficient) way to transform this set of generators to a different set (generating the same code) with lowest possible weights? I suspect that there is no efficient way, because this problem looks very similar to the [shortest basis problem of lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Shortest_basis_problem) which is conjectured to be very hard.

Comment: I guess a first and easier question is whether you can do this for parity checks of classical codes.

Comment: there will be a systematic way of doing it using, for example, binary programming. As for efficient? I don't really know, but intuition suggests not. Binary programming iteself is NP-complete and I'd guess you can encode hard instances within this specfic problem. But that's hardly a rigorous aswer ;)

Comment: Computing the distance (weight of lowest weight check) of a linear code is NP-hard. Even approximating it is hard (https://doi.org/10.1109/SFFCS.1999.814620).